# List documents using FileManager in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I am trying to list all pdf documents I have added to my Xcode project. I have a separate function that gets all the documents with the extension `pdf` and then appends a `files` variable inside the function. I am then trying to access `files` using `@State` and then list all items inside the array, but I am not sure how to access the `files` variable in the function and then add it to a list? Where am I going wrong?

```
struct PDFList: View {
    
    @State var files = GetFiles()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ForEach(0..<files.count, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(files[item])
            }
        }
    }
}

func GetFiles() -> Array<URL> {
    
    var files: [String] = []
    let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    
    do {
        let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
        let pdfFiles = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "pdf" }
        let pdfFileNames = pdfFiles.map{ $0.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent }
        
        files.append(contentsOf: pdfFileNames)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: start function names with small letter

Answer (score 0):

Add a return

```
func getFiles() -> Array<String> {    
  var files: [String] = []
  let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
 do {
    let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
    let pdfFiles = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "pdf" }
    let pdfFileNames = pdfFiles.map{ $0.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent } 
    files.append(contentsOf: pdfFileNames)
 } catch {
     print(error)
 }
 return files
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I get this error `Cannot convert return expression of type '[String]' to return type 'Array<URL>'` when `return files` is used. Also how do I access the the variable in the `@State var files`?